# Can an "it" block be called multiple times in different spec files using Page Objects

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I am fairly new to Protractor and Page Objects. I am trying to get the header to show across multiple pages. I have a header_page.js and a header_spec.js. I can verify that the header is present once within the header_spec.js (which is presently only pointing to the home page). What I would like to do is call the test for the header each time I visit a page.

```
var HomePage = require('../pages/home_page.js');
var HeaderPage = require('../pages/header_page.js');

describe('When visiting a page'. function(){
var headerPage = new HeaderPage();
var inbox_page = new HomePage();

beforeEach(function () {
    inbox_page.visit();
  });

it('header menu selector should be present', function(){
header_menu = headerPage.hdr_menu;
header_menu.click();
expect('header_menu').not.toBe(null);
  });
 });
});
```

I am not sure how to call this test from page2_spec.js..page3_spec.js as each page is different but should all contain a header. I am trying to avoid code duplication and would like to avoid calling the "it" block from each page. Do I use a helper file or can I move the it block inside the header_page.js..currently looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(){
 this.hdr_menu = element(by.css('#pick-group-btn'));
 this.hdr_img = element(by.css('PeopleAdmin logo'));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call a test spec to other specs by wrapping your spec in a function and exporting it "requiring" that module So in your case you can export header_spec.js to other modules such as page2_spec.js or page3_spec.js by :

```
          var HomePage = require('../pages/home_page.js');
          var HeaderPage = require('../pages/header_page.js');

          var commHeader = function(){

          describe('When visiting a page'. function(){
          var headerPage = new HeaderPage();
          var inbox_page = new HomePage();

          beforeEach(function () {
          inbox_page.visit();
          });

        it('header menu selector should be present', function(){
         header_menu = headerPage.hdr_menu;
         header_menu.click();
        expect('header_menu').not.toBe(null);
         });
        });
        });
         }

    module.exports = commHeader;
```

Then in you page2_spec.js file you can import this module like this :

```
       var commHeader = require('your path to spec/commHeader.js');

       describe('When visiting page 2 validate Header first'. function(){
        var headerTest = new commHeader();
           headerTest.commHeader();

       it('page 2 element validations', function(){
       //here the page 2 test goes
        });
       });
       });
```